# PropetyChanged event is null on RelativeSource binding

Tags: wpf, events, data-binding, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I use on the following `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" ItemsSource="{Binding MyModelGrid}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.XHeader}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" SelectedItem="{Binding Value.X}" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.XList,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid,Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

       //More details...

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

It's `DataContext` is the following Model:

```
public class MyModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

        private SortedDictionary<int, GridRowObj> _myModelGrid= new SortedDictionary<int,GridRowObj>();
        public SortedDictionary<int, GridRowObj> MyModelGrid
        {
            get
            {
                return _myModelGrid;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_myModelGrid!= value)
                {
                    _myModelGrid= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyModelGrid");
                }
            }
        }


        private ObservableCollection<string> _xList;
        public ObservableCollection<string> XList
        {
            get
            {
                return _xList;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_xList!= value)
                {
                    _xList= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("XList");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

The Dictonary - `MyModelGrid` initialized in 20 rows (they are displayed on the screen).

And when I put data to the list - `XList`, the `PropetyChangedEvent` is **null**, so the list is displayed empty.

I think I'm missing something in the binding. I can not understand why the event is null?

**EDIT:**

`DataContext` setting :

```
    public MyView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyViewModel vm = new MyViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm.Model;
    }
```

MyViewModel.cs:

```
public class MyViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private MyModel _model = new MyModel();
    public MyModel Model
    {
        get
        {
            return _model;
        }
        set
        {
            _model= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Model");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you setting the DataContext for the view, where does MyModelGrid reside?

Comment: @nit. In the cs code. Please note there is no problem of binding on output.

Comment: can you please share the DataContext setting and the VM that contains mymodelgrid property

Comment: The `RelativeSource Binding` is correct. How are you filling the `XList` collection?

Comment: @Sheridan. When I do XList = new  ObservableCollection<string>(); the propertychanged event is come null. That's my problem.